# SEGFPE error in old ld when trying to run a binary

Tags: c, gcc, ld, glibc

I am trying to compile binaries with heap vulnerabilities to practice binary exploitation. To do so, I need an old version of the libc so that doesn't have all the security checks the modern ones do.

I have on my computer a glibc-2.3.2.so file and a ld-2.3.2.so file. I made a small test program -

```
  7 int main()
  8 {
  9     char * first, *second;
 10     first = malloc(0x40);
 11     read(0,first,0x40);
 12     free(first);
 13     second = malloc(0x40);
 14     ((void (*)())second)();
 15 
 16 }
```

(The only thing not included are #include <stdlib.h> and #include <unistd.h>)

I turned the c file into a .o file with the command

> gcc -c firstFit.c -m32

Then, I used g++ for the linking, specifying the old glibc.

> g++ firstFit.o -o firstFit -Wl,--rpath=`pwd` -Wl,--dynamic-linker=`pwd`/ld-2.3.2.so -m32

It compiles just fine. However, when I try to run the file there is a floating point exception.

> [1]    169605 floating point exception (core dumped)  ./firstFit

I ran it under gdb to see where and

> → 0xf7fe9572                  div    DWORD PTR [ecx+0x164]

Using the gdb backtrace command

> #0  0xf7fe9572 in ?? () from /home/zac/programming/cybersec/ctfPrepChalls/heap/ld-2.3.2.so
> #1  0xf7ff6abd in ?? () from /home/zac/programming/cybersec/ctfPrepChalls/heap/ld-2.3.2.so
> #2  0xf7fe8f13 in ?? () from /home/zac/programming/cybersec/ctfPrepChalls/heap/ld-2.3.2.so
> #3  0xf7fe8c27 in ?? () from /home/zac/programming/cybersec/ctfPrepChalls/heap/ld-2.3.2.so

Why would ld be have a floating point error? How would I go about fixing this?
Help is appreciated

Comment: Not an answer, but note that `div` is an integer division: [SIGFPE](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Error-Signals.html) covers both floating-point and *other* arithmetic errors. Here probably a division by zero.

Comment: regarding: `((void (*)())second)();`   This is casting the malloc'd memory as a function pointer,   This is an error

Comment: regarding your statement: *It compiles just fine*  No, it does not.  here is the output from the compiler: *untitled1.c:13:7: warning: ISO C forbids conversion of object pointer to function pointer type*[-Wpedantic]*

Comment: To obtain a real listing from the compiler, must enable the warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: the `gdb` backtrace is missing LOTS of very useful information that the debugger: `gdb` can use to effectively display info.  Suggest adding: `-ggdb3` to both the compile and the link step

Comment: I understand that casting the malloc'd memory as a function pointer is a bad idea, and that there will be a complaint when ran due to the NX bit being set for the heap. The program was a test program for some exploit, and was not the focus of the question. It could easily be replaced with a program that just returned 0. 
I will add in the compiling flag and check it out further.

Comment: @user3629249 I added the flags to both the compilation and linking step in a new .c file which is literally just a main function that returns 0 (with stdlib.h being included). No complaints from the compiler. I run it in gdb and it crashes with the same error at the same place. I do not see what extra debugging information the -ggdb3 flag has given?

Comment: the use of the option: `-ggdb3` in both the compile and link steps will allow the `gdb` utility to display the function name(s) all the way back to the `main()` function.  It will also display the line number(s) for each file in the back trace.   HOWEVER, since the libraries are not compiled/linked with that option, such info, when stepping through a library function,  is not available to the `gdb` utility

Answer (score 0):

> Then, I used g++ for the linking, specifying the old glibc.
> `g++ firstFit.o -o firstFit -Wl,--rpath=`pwd `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=`pwd`/ld-2.3.2.so -m32`

One of the following two reasons very likely explains your crash:

1. You do not have *complete* installation of GLIBC-2.3.2 in your current directory.
   In particular, `g++` will link against `libm.so.6`, and if you end up using *system* `libm.so.6` with `$(pwd)/libc.so.6`, you are very likely to have trouble (mixing bits of GLIBC which came from different builds is a no-no).
2. You link against *system* `libstdc++.so.6`, which has `DT_GNU_HASH` and no `DT_HASH`.
   GLIBC-2.3.2 is old enough not to support `GNU_HASH`.

I expect the issue#2 is most likely explanation for `SIGFPE`.

You can confirm either of these by running

```
env LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 ./firstFit
```

to find loaded objects (do *not* use `ldd`, it will lie to you), and looking at the output from:

```
readelf -d ./firstFit | grep HASH
readelf -d /path/to/libstdc++.so.6 | grep HASH
```

Answer (score -1):

so, here is the program that only returns 0:

```
int main( void )
{
    return 0;
}
```

compiling the program

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled1.c" -o "untitled1.o" 
Compilation finished successfully.
```

linking the program (using `gcc`, not `g++`)

```
gcc -ggdb3 -o "untitled1" "untitled1.o"  
Compilation finished successfully.
```

running the program:

```
./untitled1
(nothing output)
```

Suggest: don't mix `gcc` and `g++` for the same program

Comment: I understand this, but when compiling, you haven't used --rpath or --dynamic-linker options for custom libc.so and ld.so. That is primarily where my problems seem to be coming from.

Comment: @Icarus_Incarnate,  Of course not, I don't have those obsolete library versions.  However, which version of the library is used is not amongst the problems with the OPs posted code.

Comment: Mixing `gcc` and `g++` in the same program _works  just fine_, and very likely has nothing to do with the original problem.